# MUI- data grid pro export to csv with hebrow letters get gibrish

Tags: reactjs, excel, csv, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

MUI- data grid pro export to csv with hebrow letters get gibrish
Although i add  utf8WithBom={true}
this my code:

Although i add utf8WithBom={true} this my code:

```
<DataGridPro 
components={{ Toolbar: CustomToolbar }} 
onRowDoubleClick={(row) => { window.location.href = ``; }}
 getRowId={(row) => { return byPlants.indexOf(row); }} 
localeText={heIL.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText}
 rows={byPlants} 
columns={columns} />
```

```
 function CustomToolbar() {
 return (
 <GridToolbarContainer>
 <GridToolbarExport utf8WithBom={true} /> 
</GridToolbarContainer> ); 
}
```